struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied expected 0 lifetime arguments
use crate::curve::quadratic_curve::{QuadraticCurve};
use crate::utils::mpl::{create_metadata_accounts_v3, CreateMetadataAccountsV3cpi, Metadata};
// use crate::utils::token::{create_mint, create_token_account};
use crate::state::{CurveInfo, PoolInfo};
use crate::{
    TOKEN_MINT_SEED, SOL_VAULT_SEED, TOKEN_VAULT_SEED, IPSHARE_MINT_SEED,DONUT_POOL_INFO_SEED
};
use anchor_lang::{prelude::*, system_program};
use anchor_spl::token::spl_token::state::Account;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, self, mint_to, set_authority, MintTo, SetAuthority, Token};
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    accounts::{self},
    types,
};
// use spl_token::instruction::AuthorityType;

// ipshare decimals same with token decimals
#[derive(AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize, Clone)]
pub struct CreateTokenAndBondingCurveArgs {
  pub token_name: String,
  pub token_symbol: String,
  pub token_uri: String,
  pub token_decimals: u8,
  pub ipshare_name: String,
  pub ipshare_symbol: String,
  pub ipshare_uri: String,
  pub m_coefficient: u64,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(args: CreateTokenAndBondingCurveArgs)]
pub struct CreateTokenAndBondingCurve<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub admin: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    init,
    seeds = [args.token_name.as_bytes(), DONUT_POOL_INFO_SEED.as_bytes()],
    bump,
    payer = admin,
    space = 8 + PoolInfo::LEN,
  )]
  pub pool_info: Account<'info, PoolInfo>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [args.token_name.as_bytes(), SOL_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes()],
    bump,
  )]
  pub sol_vault: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [args.token_name.as_bytes(), TOKEN_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes()],
    bump,
  )]
  pub token_vault: UncheckedAccount<'info>,


  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [args.token_name.as_bytes(), TOKEN_MINT_SEED.as_bytes()],
    bump,
  )]
  pub token_mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    address = accounts::Metadata::find_pda(&token_mint.key()).0,
  )]
  pub token_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [args.ipshare_name.as_bytes(), IPSHARE_MINT_SEED.as_bytes()],
    bump,
  )]
  pub ipshare_mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    address = accounts::Metadata::find_pda(&ipshare_mint.key()).0,
  )]
  pub ipshare_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
  pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
  pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
}

impl<'info> CreateTokenAndBondingCurve<'info> {

}

my code looks almost like it, and it is my Cargo.toml settings it looks like
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
mpl-token-metadata = "4.1.2"
solana-program = "1.18.14"

I got error
`struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied
expected 0 lifetime argumentsrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
state.rs(89, 12): struct defined here, with 0 lifetime parameters
create_token_and_bonding_curve.rs(41, 27): remove this lifetime argument
struct takes 0 generic arguments but 1 generic argument was supplied
expected 0 generic argumentsrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
state.rs(89, 12): struct defined here, with 0 generic parameters
create_token_and_bonding_curve.rs(41, 34): remove this generic argument` 

in the linke   pub pool_vault: Account<'info, PoolVault>, and line pub pool_info: Account<'info, LaunchInfo>,, anyone can give me some suggestions?

You've imported the Account from the SPL Token account, and not the Anchor account. Try to remove use anchor_spl::token::spl_token::state::Account; since the Anchor Account is part of the Anchor prelude.
